# Compiling Meteor Project with

Tags: node.js, angular, meteor

I'm working with a Meteor Angular 2 Tutorial.

```
client/imports/app/parties/parties-list.component.ts (6, 43): Module '"node_modules/ng2-pagination/index"' has no exported member 'PaginationControlsCmp'.
    client/imports/app/parties/parties-list.component.ts (72, 37): Argument of type '{ id: () => string; itemsPerPage: number; currentPage: number; totalItems: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'PaginationInstance'.
      Types of property 'id' are incompatible.
        Type '() => string' is not assignable to type 'string'.
    client/imports/app/parties/parties-list.component.ts (86, 44): Argument of type '() => string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
    cl
```

Working back through the issues, one thing I've seen on github forums is one line:

```
import { PaginationService, PaginatePipe, PaginationControlsCmp } from 'ng2-pagination';
```

But I haven't been able to make this work. I'm very new to this, so I'm trying to trace this back to where the problem is starting. I found the following:

**EDITED**

Including code for reference.

Having installed:

```
meteor npm install ng2-pagination --save
```

Imported:

```
import { Ng2PaginationModule } from 'ng2-pagination';

+┊  ┊11┊interface Pagination {
+┊  ┊12┊  limit: number;
+┊  ┊13┊  skip: number;
+┊  ┊14┊}
+┊  ┊15┊
+┊  ┊16┊interface Options extends Pagination {
+┊  ┊17┊  [key: string]: any
+┊  ┊18┊}

+┊  ┊36┊  constructor(
+┊  ┊37┊    private paginationService: PaginationService
+┊  ┊38┊  ) {}

+┊  ┊65┊    this.paginationService.register({
+┊  ┊66┊      id: this.paginationService.defaultId,
+┊  ┊67┊      itemsPerPage: 10,
+┊  ┊68┊      currentPage: 1,
+┊  ┊69┊      totalItems: 30,
+┊  ┊70┊    });
```

...

```
+┊  ┊52┊      this.paginationService.setCurrentPage(this.paginationService.defaultId, curPage as number);
```

And finally the pagination element:

```
+┊  ┊17┊  <pagination-controls (pageChange)="onPageChanged($event)"></pagination-controls>
enter code here
I think I've done this all correctly, as per the tutorial, and altered as per the issues, but cannot get it working.
```

This is where I'm stuck: (sept 13)

https://github.com/Urigo/meteor-angular2.0socially/blob/master/manuals/views/step13.md

Comment: Added an answer, not sure if I jumped the gun here... but could you include your code where and how you are using this module. Where & how have you declared it, how have you used it etc. Showing us an error message is not enough, as we don't know how your code looks like!

Comment: I attached the tutorial I'm working off at the top, but didn't link to a page number. My mistake.

Comment: That doesn't still help, we need to see YOUR code, e.g how do you import it, how do you use it, possibly configuration files, but let's start out with at least showing us how you imported it and how have you installed the package. I guess by following the instructions, but list the steps anyway, maybe you'll yourself find an error when you do it ;) We need code snippets. Even though you are using a tutorial, we want to see the relevant code related to your question, to be able to sort out the problem (if we can).

Comment: And anyhow, we shouldn't need to "do the work" and sift through pages of code and try to find the important parts. And this I say in a totally friendly manner, some users might have lost their nerv by now and bark at you :D

Comment: And I don't mean you have to list the steps of the meteor project, just the pagination. :)

Comment: My intention was for others to see a broader scope beyond just the individual code of a single file, or even numerous files, including related resources that I've found that seem related and unresolved in the case of a number of people. I'm not looking for people to do my work for me. I can post all the code, but I have been trepidatious about that because it's going  to be a lot of code possibly out of context. I can edit my post accordingly.

Comment: No worries man, I'm not here to tell you how to write your question. I must have misunderstood. I thought you wished to have a specific solution :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm working with `ngPagination` as well, but I'm really not understanding your import. That is probably causing your problem, since you are trying to import something that shouldn't and can't be imported. You should import it to your `@NgModule` just like so:

```
import { Ng2PaginationModule } from 'ng2-pagination';
```

and declare it in your `imports` in `@NgModule`:

```
imports: [Ng2PaginationModule ...+ your other imports]
```

and then you can use it in your components (html) without importing anything to your components, since you have already declared it in your `@NgModule`, e.g like so:

```
<table>
    <tr *ngFor="let item of array | paginate: {itemsPerPage: 10, currentPage: p }">
        <td>{{item.value}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

where `p` is a variable of your choosing.

Hope this helps!